# Вопрос на собеседовании

Tags: искусственный-интеллект

Страховые компании иногда устанавливают телеметрические приборы в автомобиль. Они определяют характер вождения (скорость, динамика, повороты, экстренные торможения) и, если по статистике оно не аварийно, делают скидку водителю на полис.

Прибыль страховых компаний, в то же время, формируется только за счет тех, кто не попадает в аварии часто. Но ведь соглашаться поставить телеметрическое устройство будут именно аккуратные водители, а те, кто любит погонят – на это не пойдут.

Вопрос: стоит ли страховщику создавать мобильное приложение, позволяющее любому желающему включить скоринг (отслеживание через акселерометр устройства), учитывая, что им в первую очередь воспользуются хорошие водители, приносящие основные доход страховой компании, и почему?

Comment: Под полисом подразумевается страхование ответственности? Или каско? Выводы для них скорее всего будут разные :)

Comment: И ещё результат сильно зависит от доли конкретной страховой на рынке :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот только причем тут искусственный интеллект? Это тест на самый естественный, точнее на проверку логики тестируемого.

Скорее всего, даже "тот кто любит погонять" в надежде на скидку страховой (а в цивилизованных странах во-первых, страховой платеж весьма высок, а во-вторых скидка может быть очень ощутима) может взять такой прибор контроля, в надежде эту самую скидку получить. И начнет  ездить более аккуратно. В итоге - процент аварий снизится, а выплат страховой придется делать меньше.

И еще одна ваша логическая ошибка. Прибыль (а не доход!) компании формируется не "хорошими водителями", а разницей между суммарным размером платежей застрахованных и суммарной выплатой по случаю ДТП. Чем меньше выплат, тем больше прибыль. В принципе, страховая тут вообще ничего не теряет.

Хотя, конечно, приличная страховая сначала строит соответствующую модель (типа падение платежей->снижение аварийности->снижение выплат -> профит, но это точно не модель ИИ ), на которой и проверяет свой возможный выигрыш. Отсюда легко найти ответ на вопрос про мобильное приложение, зная стоимость его разработки и поддержки.